# Geometry solve for $x$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: triangle]

Since the last angle is $77^\circ,$ can I solve this by using law of sines? This would lead us to:

$$\frac{519}{\sin\left(77^\circ\right)}=\frac{190+x}{\sin \left( 60^\circ \right)}$$

And the answer would be $\sim271,29$ meters

Comment: This equation is linear due to $x$

Comment: I rollback your question so that others sees your thoughts and effort (applying the law of sines) for this question.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this was down-voted and why there are votes to close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make $x$ the *subject* of your equation.
$$x+190=519\times\frac{\sin{60^\circ}}{\sin{77^\circ}}$$
$$x=519\times\frac{\sin{60^\circ}}{\sin{77^\circ}}-190\approx 271.29$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I used `^\circ` instead of `°` so as to type fast.  Then I [converted $^\circ$ to $°$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19678/290189) due to semantic reasons.